# Camera pointing with Python not working

Tags: python, camera

I'm trying to update the position of the camera using Python, so that I can batch render a scene from various angles.

If I start with the default cube scene, then try to move the camera, the pointing doesn't seem to work. Here's a simple script I've tried:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
import os, glob, math

def look_at(obj_camera, point):
    loc_camera = obj_camera.matrix_world.to_translation()

    direction = point - loc_camera
    # point the cameras '-Z' and use its 'Y' as up
    rot_quat = direction.to_track_quat('-Z', 'Y')

    # assume we're using euler rotation
    obj_camera.rotation_euler = rot_quat.to_euler()


# print where the camera currently is
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
print("Current camera location:" + str(cam.location))
print("Camera pointing at " + str(cam.rotation_euler))

# move the camera, and print again
cam.location = (0, 0, 25)
look_at(cam,Vector((0,0,0)))
print("New camera location: " + str(cam.location))
print("Camera pointing at " + str(cam.rotation_euler))

print("Done.")
```

The result in the console is:

```
Current camera location:<Vector (4.9719, -4.6602, 3.1567)>
Camera pointing at <Euler (x=1.1147, y=-0.0000, z=0.8157), order='XYZ'>
New camera location: <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 25.0000)>
Camera pointing at <Euler (x=1.1370, y=-0.0000, z=0.8177), order='XYZ'>
Done.
```

In the GUI, I see that the position of the camera has moved, but the camera is not pointing at the origin, and so we can't see the cube.

It's almost as if the look_at() function isn't getting called.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to programmatically move the camera position and orientation?

Comment: Use `obj_camera.location` instead of `loc_camera`. [See this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#stale-data)